# How can I create a Fluent NHibernate Convention that ignores properties that don't have setters

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, conventions

I'm looking for a [FluentNH](http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/) (Fluent NHibernate) convention or configuration that ignores all properties that have no setter:

It would still map these:

```
public class foo{
  public virtual int bar {get; private set;}
}
```

And omit these:

```
public class foo{
  public virtual int fizz{get;private set;}
  public virtual int bar{get {return fizz;}} //<-------
}
```

Comment: +1 Interesting question. I normally just create a getter-method: `GetBar()`, which in addition makes its intend clearer to its users (but that's not a solution to your issue, of course).

Comment: @Abel that's acceptable workaround though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use a custom mapping configuration

```
public class DefaultMappingConfiguration : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
{
    public override bool ShouldMap(Member member)
    {
        return member.CanWrite;
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
var nhConfiguration = new Configuration().Configure();
var mappingConfiguration = new DefaultMappingConfiguration();

var.fluentConfiguration = Fluently.Configure(nhConfiguration );
    .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(
        AutoMap.AssemblyOf<MappedType>(mappingConfiguration)
    ));

var sessionFactory = this.fluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory();
```

However, private setters won't get mapped. You should get them as protected

Comment: This omits props with `private set;`.

Comment: +1: simple, fine and as it should be done with FluentNH (but remove that stroked first line... ;). PS: note that `CanWrite` returns false when there's a private setter (I think).

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
public class DefaultMappingConfiguration : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
{
    public override bool ShouldMap(Member member)
    {
        if (member.IsProperty && !member.CanWrite)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return base.ShouldMap(member);
    }
}
```

That should handle the case of no setter and private setter.

Comment: I kind a started using methods instead. Would like to accept it but a bit lazy to test it atm. :)

Comment: Well it works for me and my production code, but I don't use any private setters. I'm not sure if NHibernate can deal with properties with private setters.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question but code below do well with private setters.

```
public override bool ShouldMap(Member member)
{
    var prop = member.DeclaringType.GetProperty(member.Name);
    bool isPropertyToMap = 
        prop != null &&
        prop.GetSetMethod(true) != null &&
        member.IsProperty;

    return
        base.ShouldMap(member) && isPropertyToMap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use an attribute.

```
public class MyEntity
{
    [NotMapped]
    public bool A => true;
}

public class AutomappingConfiguration : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
{
    public override bool ShouldMap(Member member)
    {
        if (member.MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NotMappedAttribute), true).Length > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return base.ShouldMap(member);
    }
}
```